Is it possible to name variables throughout an org mode document and then calculate it somewhere without using tables?
I would like to set variables scattered throughout a document and then total them at some place in the document.
For example,
#+NAME: apples 10

And then I have some
#+NAME: pears 5

And a some point later
Total: $apples + $pears

Result: 15

You could define the variables inline using elisp (or any other language, eg. src_emacs-lisp{...}).
For example,
I have src_emacs-lisp{(setq apples 10)} apples.

and src_emacs-lisp{(setq pears 5)} pears.

for a total of: src_emacs-lisp{(+ apples pears)} fruits.

Alternatively, using named blocks like you're example, the values could be defined in source blocks and summed later in another block or inline. This seems like a bit more work - I'm not sure how to define the name/value inline without the source block.
#+NAME: apples
#+BEGIN_SRC emacs-lisp :var apples=10 :results none
apples
#+END_SRC

#+NAME: pears
#+BEGIN_SRC emacs-lisp :var pears=5 :results none
pears
#+END_SRC

Total = src_emacs-lisp{(+ apples pears)}

